# snake and ladder program

Tags: c++, codeblocks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#define MAX_NUM 6
using namespace std;
int randomfunc(int &score);
int main()
{
int p1_score=0,p2_score=0;
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;
cout<<"========================================"<<endl;
cout<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t\t\t SNAKE AND LADDER GAME \t\t\t\t"<<endl;
cout<<endl;
cout<<"========================================"<<endl;
cout<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t\tdesigned by bennyyy\t\t\t"<<endl;
cout<<"========================================"<<endl;
int i;
string player1,player2;

srand(time(0));

cout<<"enter the name of  player 1"<<endl;
cin>>player1;
cout<<"enter the name of the player 2 "<<endl;
cin>>player2;
cout<<"the position of player1 and player2 is 0 initially"<<endl;

while(p1_score<100 && p2_score<100)
{

cout<<player1<<" It is your turn press any key to play "<<endl;
cin.get();
randomfunc(p1_score);
cout<<"your score is "<<p1_score<<endl;
cout<<player2<<"it is your turn press any key to play"<<endl;
cin.get();
randomfunc(p2_score);
cout<<"your score is "<<p2_score<<endl;

}
if(p1_score>p2_score)
{
cout<<player1<<"is the winner"<<endl;
}
if(p2_score>p1_score)
{
cout<<player2<<"is the winner"<<endl;
}
if(p1_score==p2_score)
{
cout<<"match is draw"<<endl;
}
}
int randomfunc(int &score)
{
int random;
random=rand()%MAX_NUM;
cout<<"your number is "<<random<<endl;
score=random+score;
switch(score)
{
case 98 :score=28;
     cout<<"you ran into a snake!"<<endl;

    break;
case 95 :score=24;
cout<<"you ran into a snake!"<<endl;

break;
case 92 :score=51;
cout<<"you ran into a snake!"<<endl;

break;
case 83 :score=19;
cout<<"you ran into a snake!"<<endl;

break;
case 73 :score=1;
cout<<"you ran into a snake!"<<endl;

break;
case 69 :score=33;
cout<<"you ran into a snake!"<<endl;

break;
case 64 :score=36;
cout<<"you ran into a snake!"<<endl;

break;
case 59 :score=17;
cout<<"you ran into a snake!"<<endl;

break;
case 55 :score=7;
cout<<"you ran into a snake!"<<endl;

break;
case 52 :score=11;
cout<<"you ran into a snake!"<<endl;

break;
case 48 :score=9;
cout<<"you ran into a snake!"<<endl;

break;
case 46 :score=5;
cout<<"you ran into a snake!"<<endl;

break;
case 44 :score=22;
cout<<"you ran into a snake!"<<endl;

break;
case 8 :score=26;
cout<<"luckyyy boy u got ladder"<<endl;

break;
case 21 :score=82;
cout<<"luckyyy boy u got ladder"<<endl;

break;
case 43 :score=77;
 cout<<"luckyyy boy u got ladder"<<endl;

break;
case 50 :score=91;
cout<<"luckyyy boy u got ladder"<<endl;

break;
case 54 :score=93;
cout<<"luckyyy boy u got ladder"<<endl;

break;
case 62 :score=96;
cout<<"luckyyy boy u got ladder"<<endl;

break;
case 66 :score=87;
cout<<"luckyyy boy u got ladder"<<endl;

break;
case 80 :score=100;
cout<<"luckyyy boy u got ladder"<<endl;

}
return score;
}
```

since it is 2 players
In output it is asking only player 2 to press key but for player 1 it is not asking. but shows the message and it performs next operations. for each player i gave cin.get() so that  it asks the user to press any key but this action is performed only at the player 2 . Can anyone tell me the mistake?

Comment: Please narrow down the code to the parts where you have the problems. *Where* is the input wrong? *What* is the input? What is the *expected* and *actual* output?

Comment: the output should ask first the player name and then it should ask the player 1and player 2 to press any key when player 1 or 2 presses the key it generates a random number and displays the score but instead player1 is played by the computer only player 2 is asking to press the key

Comment: Please indent the code - makes it easier to read

Answer (score 0):

When you type something and enter in `cin`, it seems that `cin` leaves the `'\n'` out and your next `cin.get` receives that enter key. To fix it, change the part:

```
cout<<"the position of player1 and player2 is 0 initially"<<endl;
while(p1_score<100 && p2_score<100)
```

into:

```
cout<<"the position of player1 and player2 is 0 initially"<<endl;
cin.get();
while(p1_score<100 && p2_score<100)
```

**Another approach:**

The above way does the job fine. However the following code is better. It ignores your additional `'\n'`:

```
cout<<"the position of player1 and player2 is 0 initially"<<endl;
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
while(p1_score<100 && p2_score<100)
```

Note that for INT_MAX you need additional library:

```
#include <climits>
```

or, you may replace `INT_MAX` with a big number such as 10000.

Comment: I can't get u .I want both the players to ask "press any key to play" and when i press the key it should show me the result , and i'm not pressing any arrow keys ,i'm pressing alphabets even though it is not working